# Bounded inverse for a closed range closed operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators, closed-graph

I am dealing with an unbounded operator $T$ on an Hilbert space $H$. I am interested in proving that it has a bounded inverse $T^{-1}$. I managed to prove that the operator is closed and self-adjoint. By the Closed Range theorem I have that $\mathcal{R}(T)=\ker(T)^{\perp}$. If $\ker T$ would have been trivial then $T^{-1}$ would have been defined on the whole space and by the Closed Graph Theorem it had to bounded. Unfortunately $\ker T \neq \{0\}$, but I know that $\dim \ker < \infty$. Is it still possible to have a bounded inverse? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Are you studying a particular operator? What you claim is not true in general even for bounded operators. For example the range does not need to be closed.

Comment: Yes, it is the Boltzman Operator. I managed to prove all I have stated above, but I am interested in proving the boundedness of $T^{-1}$ even if the kernel is non-trivial, but finite dimensional.

Comment: I do not know much about this particular operator. You have mentioned that the operator is closed. This property follows also from the  selfadjointness. But how do you know that the range is closed ?